# Can not submit application to spark-cluster in code

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

My code is:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("plzzzz").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().format("libsvm").load("/home/ceny/tools/123.txt");
KMeans kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L);
KMeansModel model = kmeans.fit(dataset);//this line is 20
```

The error is:

```
16/12/19 00:08:49 WARN KMeans: The input data was not directly cached, which may hurt performance if its parent RDDs are also uncached.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
    at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel.transform(KMeans.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.fit(KMeans.scala:326)
    at Test.main(Test.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

My build.gradle is:

```
compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-reflect', version: '2.11.8'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.0.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.0.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-mllib_2.10', version: '2.0.2'
```

My environment is :

> spark-version:2.0.2
>
> scala-version:2.11.8

Description:

I try to execute below code in IDEA,error appears.
If I package it as JAR,then submit it in termial,everything is fine.

While if I Use `SparkSubmit.main()` to submit the jar by code,the error still appears.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the same Scala version for all artifacts. It should be:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-mllib_2.11', version: '2.0.2'
```

Comment: Yes,Thank you! I search **spark** in maven repository,and the **advertisement**  let me think that the count of results is just 7.